# Last line cut off in UITextView when text contains a long line

Tags: ios, uitextview

I'm trying to use a UITextView to display static text, but as soon as I have a long line somewhere in the text, and last line of the text gets cut off (isn't displayed).

My settings on the text view are: not selectable, not editable and no scroll enabled.

A long line means a line that is wrapped to 6 lines and more, 5 lines or less seems to work as expected.

Example text that causes this problem:

```
Line 1
Line 2 which is really long ...
Line 3
Line 4
```

In this example, if line 2 is wrapped to 6 lines or more, then Line 4 will not be visible.

The app is targeting iOS 7, my phone runs 8.3.

Might also be worth mentioning that I'm using this text view in a `UITableViewCell` with automatic dimension.

Comment: use of auto layout will help you

Comment: from your settings, why not use `UILabel`?

Comment: I'm using auto layout (through code, vfl). Also, had similar problems with UILabel.